Use tri-state logic in Verilog to have two drivers on a wire
How can I model this circuit diagram in Verilog with some straightforward tri-state logic?

Each driver module will be enabled one at a time, and the reader module just reads the signal.
I'm just interested in a tri-state solution. I would like to avoid any multiplexors.

Does In VHDL, How to implement two tristate buffers driving the same pin with a PULLUP? on Stack Overflow help? The question has a Verilog example, and one answer shows a VHDL example.

What is this for?  Toolics answer below is correct for the verilog language or if you are looking to run something in a simulator.  If you want to synthesize this for a particular target there may be better options, for instance FPGAs often have IO pin macros that handle this.

There are many ways to model a tri-state driver in Verilog.  Here is a common way:
module driver1 (output data);
    reg enable, data_internal;
    assign data = (enable) ? data_internal : 1'bz;
endmodule

module driver2 (output data);
    reg enable, data_internal;
    assign data = (enable) ? data_internal : 1'bz;
endmodule

module tb;
    wire data;
    driver1 driver1 (data);
    driver2 driver2 (data);
endmodule

When a module's internal enable signal is 1, that module drives the common data bus with the module's internal data.  Otherwise, both modules drive the high-impedance value 1'bz.
